# Horizontally aligned divs in liquid layout - background of one extends behind other

Tags: html, css

I have a liquid layout. I need 2 divs to be next to each other horizontally and take up the full available width. The 2nd div needs to be the width of its content, so the 1st div should take up the rest of the space.

Here is my attempt:
http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/N2prR/2/

Its working except that the background of #other extends behind #button. Im my actual site #other also has a background image set to its right. This means that I need the background colour and image to only extend up to #button, not beyond it. Thanks

Comment: is it a requirement that those two divs cannot have any width set at all

Comment: Yes. 'Cause you need to set the width of at least one <div>.

Comment: Surely you will have to set the width of your first div if you don't want it to be computed as width: 100%; Why don't you set both divs to a percentage width?

Comment: @verisimilitude you've just linked to my fiddle, is that what you meant to do?

Comment: @trickeedickee I want #button to be the width of its content, not 20% (or whatever) of the page width.

Comment: I'll post the entire HTML for you as an answer to this question. I had modified your fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

1st of all both divs should be floated. (if not they are exist in different "layers" and overlaps)

As to the auto width thing, I don`t think you can do it that easily just with html. In my experience its always better to work with set width/height with divs.

If you want you can use a 2 td table (one  with set to 100% width, the other to set width - e.g. 200px)

Good luck

Comment: Really dont want to start using tables for layout, seems it might be the only option though.

Comment: You've linked to my fiddle, without any changes. Thanks

Comment: Its close but is there a way to make #button only as wide as its content (as it would if it were displayed inline). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
#other {
    background-color: blue;
width: 40%;
}
#button {
   background-color: gold;
   float: right;
   border-radius: 10px;
   width: 60%; 
}
.clear{
   clear: both;
}
```

```
<div id="parent"> 
 <div id="button">
    Submit Submit Submit Submit Submit Submit Submit Submit Submit Submit
 </div> 
 <div id="other"> 
   Some other content
 </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Mandatory for you to give the 1st <div>  some fixed with in percentage. The text in the second  will wrap automatically.

Comment: Ive saved your code into a fiddle here but it doenst seem to o work http://jsfiddle.net/jamesbrighton/STVQK/

Comment: I've made changes to your fiddle :-). Assigned width: 60% to #button1. It will now word-wrap the text automatically. Let me know if this is fine for you. This fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/STVQK/1/

Comment: No, I wanted #button to only but the width of its content. So if you only had one 'submit' text, it would be much shorter. Thanks